# How to make numerical field name CLS compliant?

Tags: c#, dataset, rdlc, cls

I am working on .net framework 3.5 and using RDLC files for reporting in my project.
Problem that I am facing is that in my Dataset I have a numerically named field "63" and whenever I am using it in my RDLC file its showing me this error

"A field in the dataset ‘DataSet1’ has the name ‘63’. Field names must be CLS-compliant identifiers."

I have already performed few things like.

1.) [assembly: CLSCompliantAttribute(false)]

in my project's assemblyInfo.cs

2.) and placing attribute name under square brackets. eg :[63] in my Dataset.

But all went futile any help will be appreciated Thank You

Comment: The warning is saying that it must be CLS-Compliant.. CLS compliance means you can't declare a variable/field/property starting with a number.. or a square bracket. Very strange naming convention you have there.. :/

Comment: I am having no control on database, and to fetch data from database my dataset schema should have to be same as that of db table schema(Same name and same type properties). So I am feeling a bit stuck up. :-?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, then try this.

1. Open the xsd file.
2. Right click on the table.
3. Select configure.
4. Assign an alias in the select statement.
5. Update report.

This [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1672435.aspx/1) might help u out

Comment: Thank you for the answer but my Datatable configure option is not enabled. Rest I have already gone through this link.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got an answer for it.
only thing that is to be done is to change the name of the variable like fro "63" to "a63". To turn the name alphanumeric.